# Change Enable32BitAppOnWin64 programmatcially in c++

Tags: c++, iis, installation

For a web application, in the msi installer, I used a custom dll and trying the following C++ code to enable 32-bit application on win64 for an application pool, the  hr result shows success but still the Enable32BitAppOnWin64 is false for the application pool. pSiteElem is IAppHostElement type and already validated by getting the name of the application pool successfully.

```
VARIANT vtEnable32Bit;
vtEnable32Bit.vt = VT_BOOL;
vtEnable32Bit.boolVal = true;               
hr = pSiteElem->SetMetadata(L"Enable32BitAppOnWin64", vtEnable32Bit);
if(FAILED(hr))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Enable32BitAppOnWin64: ",L"FAILED", MB_OK);
}
else
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Enable32BitAppOnWin64: ",L"success", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `hr`?

Comment: I used this code to convert hr to string and it is "The operation completed successfully."   com_error err(hr);
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();

Comment: When you say "custom Dll" does that mean this is an MSI custom action? Also, if this is a server OS there is no 32-bit subsystem.

Comment: Yes, the custom dll does a lot of tasks including creates new application in iis and assign an app pool to it,... everything works correctly, except setting Enable32BitAppOnWin64. The web application is 32-bit application and I tested in Windows 8.1 and windows 2016 in Azure both 64-bit system and the the application is installed in c:\program files (x86) folder and I don't think there is a subsystem.